# New user added to TFS has different settings than rest of users

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I have 2 issues going on with TFS.

We have 2 active directory roles set up for TFS and Visual Studio 2015: ADMINS and USERS.  And we have one main Team Project.

We recently hired two contractors and added them to our USERS role.  But what we have noticed is that on their machines, as soon as they start to edit the files, it shows as [lock, edit] where everyone else shows just [edit].  The primary difference that we know of is they have Windows 10 where the other developers are on Windows 7.  I have been trying to troubleshoot this for the past week with no success.  Any suggestions on what I can look at/query to find this?  This isn't stopping us, but still having to workaround it.

Then mid morning one of these contractors was trying to edit some Shared Datasets.  And now he keeps getting "Access to path [filepath] is denied"  but so far it looks to only be happening on *.rsd and *.rds.  He was able to create a Dataset, commit it to TFS.  But then is unable to edit it.  But he can then delete and commit the deletion to TFS.  This is completely stopping him for working on these, so this is more of an issue currently.

I saw a post about checking the local file properties to see if it is read only.  We did try to change the readonly setting.  The file updated but it won't show in TFS Pending Changes or allow him to Undo the change.  We currently have 3 solution with a ssrs project.  He gets the same issue in all.  I had another developer who is in the USERS role validate that she can edit.

Any suggestions on how I can trouble shoot these items is appreciated.

Comment: Are your contractors using server workspaces and taking out exclusive locks?

Comment: @Amanda Have you checked the contractor's account on other clients, (e.g  on Windows 7) ? Does it have the same issue?

Comment: We all are using local workspaces on c:\ , not server workspace

Answer (score 0):

For the `[lock, edit]` issue, if the user select lock type (e.g Check in- ... Check Out-...) when `Check Out for Edit...` then it will show as `[lock, edit]`.

For the "`Access to path [filepath] is denied`" issue, seems it's related to permission settings on your local machine or AD. So, please check if the user has the correct permission to access the the shared path/files. For the specific files, make sure they are not read-only.

To troubleshoot that, just try below things:

- Try the contractor's account on other clients, (e.g on Windows 7) to
  check if it has the same issue.
- Try move the user from **USERS** role, then add the user separately
  in TFS and give the corresponding permissions, then check if it has
  the same issue.
- Check **Security** and **Version Control** settings and make sure no
  restrics.

  [image]